# How to set your pg_hba.conf file in a Docker container?

Tags: postgresql

Good day!

I have a task to delimit user access to databases

for example, that user_1 would have access only to the database of "oranges" and user_2 only to the database of "watermelons"

I try to do this through pg_hba.conf, but I can still connect to the watermelon database through user_1

**MY pg_hba.conf**

```
# PostgreSQL Client Authentication Configuration File
# ===================================================
#
# Refer to the "Client Authentication" section in the PostgreSQL
# documentation for a complete description of this file.  A short
# synopsis follows.
#
# This file controls: which hosts are allowed to connect, how clients
# are 
#...



# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
# local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
# host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
# host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
# local   replication     all                                     trust
# host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# host    replication     all             ::1/128                 trust

# host all all all scram-sha-256

host    oranges user_1  password
host    watermelons user_2  password
```

**MY DOCKERFILE**

```
FROM postgres:14.1
RUN rm -f /var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf
COPY ./pg_hba.conf /var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf
ADD ./init.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["postgres"]
```

**MY DOCKER-COMPOSE**

```yaml
version: "3.9"
services:

  #DATABASE_SERVER
  postgres:
    build: ./databases/postgres
    hostname: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: root
      PGDATA: /var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
```

What am I doing wrong? I will be grateful for any comment!

Comment: Check what is actually in the file matches what you think is there.

Comment: `select * from pg_hba_file_rules;`, see: [How do I query the running pg_hba configuration?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/181639/how-do-i-query-the-running-pg-hba-configuration)

Comment: @Luuk indeed, my configuration does not seem to exist. How to enable my configuration?